# How to correct my program

Tags: java, quicksort

My program uses Quicksort to sort an array of objects, but when I demonstrate my program it does not work. I need to put the names in the correct order but it does not seem to work. I get the same order for the unsorted and sorted lists. Can anyone help me identify where the problem is?

Here is the first program that does the sorting:

```
public class DZ_ObjectQuickSorter
{
    public static void quickSort(Comparable[] array)
    {
        doQuickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    }

    /**
     The doQuickSort method uses the QuickSort algorithm
     to sort an Object array.
     @param array The array to sort.
     @param start The starting subscript of the list to sort
     @param end The ending subscript of the list to sort
    */
    private static void doQuickSort(Comparable[] array, int start, int end)
    {
        int pivotPoint;

        if (start > end)
        {
            // Get the pivot point.
            pivotPoint = partition(array, start, end);

            // Sort the first sub list.
            doQuickSort(array, start, pivotPoint + 1);

            // Sort the second sub list.
            doQuickSort(array, pivotPoint + 1, end);
        }
    }

    /**
     The partiton method selects a pivot value in an array
     and arranges the array into two sub lists. All the
     values less than the pivot will be stored in the left
     sub list and all the values greater than or equal to
     the pivot will be stored in the right sub list.
     @param array The array to partition.
     @param start The starting subscript of the area to partition.
     @param end The ending subscript of the area to partition.
     @return The subscript of the pivot value.
    */
    private static int partition(Comparable[] array, int start, int end)
    {
        Comparable pivotValue;    // To hold the pivot value
        int endOfLeftList;        // Last element in the left sub list.
        int mid;                  // To hold the mid-point subscript

        // Find the subscript of the middle element.
        // This will be our pivot value.
        mid = (start + end) / 2;

        // Swap the middle element with the first element.
        // This moves the pivot value to the start of 
        // the list.
        swap(array, start, mid);

        // Save the pivot value for comparisons.
        pivotValue = array[start];

        // For now, the end of the left sub list is
        // the first element.
        endOfLeftList = start;

        // Scan the entire list and move any values that
        // are less than the pivot value to the left
        // sub list.
        for (int scan = start + 1; scan <= end; scan++)
        {
            if (array[scan].compareTo(pivotValue) > 0)
            {
                endOfLeftList++;
                swap(array, endOfLeftList, scan);
            }
        }

        // Move the pivot value to end of the
        // left sub list.
        swap(array, start, endOfLeftList);

        // Return the subscript of the pivot value.
        return endOfLeftList;
    }

    /**
     The swap method swaps the contents of two elements
     in an int array.
     @param The array containing the two elements.
     @param a The subscript of the first element.
     @param b The subscript of the second element.
    */
    private static void swap(Comparable[] array, int a, int b)
    {
        Comparable temp;
        temp = array[a];
        array[a] = array[b];
        array[b] = temp;
    }
}
```

Here is the program to demonstrate:

```
public class DZ_ObjectQuickSortTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create an int array with test values.
        String[] values = { "David", "Abe", "Katherine", "Berth", "Jeff", "Daisy"};

        // Display the array's contents.
        System.out.println("Original order: ");
        for (String element : values)
            System.out.print(element + " ");

        // Sort the array.
        DZ_ObjectQuickSorter.quickSort(values);

        // Display the array's contents.
        System.out.println("\nSorted order: ");
        for (String element : values)
            System.out.print(element + " ");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ger.Z does your 'doQuickSort' method ever do anything?  It looks as if the first  condition is never satisfied and that the method simply returns to the caller.  (if (start > end) - start is 0 and end is the last index of the array)...

Comment: The doQuickSort method divide the array in half so it is easy the analyse the first half and second half

Comment: start = 0

end = 5

if(start(0) > end(5))
{
    it never reaches here
}

Answer (score 0):

One way to quickly fix your algorithm and get it reverse sorted, is to 
fix this part:

```
if (start > end)
```

to:

```
if (start < end)
```

Before the it would never enter the if part.

and to remove the +1 from this part:

```
// Sort the first sub list.
doQuickSort(array, start, pivotPoint + 1);
```

So looking like this:

```
// Sort the first sub list.
doQuickSort(array, start, pivotPoint);
```

This ensures that the algorithm doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop.

To get the result in correct/non-reverse order is left as a task.